# Conditions - parsing grammar SableCC

Tags: parsing, grammar, ambiguous, sablecc

I'm using sableCC and I try to built a grammar that accepts conditions like in C.However I'm getting errors when I try to add parentheses on my conditions because there is a conflict with the parentheses I have for the expressions.
eg it accepts 4 = 3 or x = 95 mod 5 and 5 = 5 but without any parentheses.Also I feel like the 'not' grammar-rule is not correct.

```
Helpers
    tab   = 9;
    cr    = 13;
    lf    = 10;

    sign = '+' | '-';
    digit = ['0'..'9'];

    lowercase = ['a'..'z'];
    uppercase = ['A'..'Z'];
    letter  = lowercase | uppercase;
    idletter = letter | '_';
    idchar  = letter | '_' | digit;

Tokens
    number  = [digit - '0'] digit*;
    id = idletter idchar*;
    plus   = '+';
    minus  = '-';
    times  = '*';
    div = 'div';
    mod = 'mod';

    equal = '=';
    hash = '#';
    greater = '>';
    greateq = '>=';
    less    = '<';
    lesseq  = '<=';
    not = 'not';
    and = 'and';
    or  = 'or';

    lparen = '(';
    rparen = ')';

    eol   = cr | lf | cr lf;
    blank = ' ' | tab;

Ignored Tokens

    eol, blank;

Productions

    program = compare*;

expr = {term} term
      | {add} expr plus term
      | {sub}  expr minus term
      ;
term = {factor} factor
      | {times}  term times factor
      | {div}  term div factor
      | {mod}  term mod factor
      ;
factor = {number} number
       | {id} id
       | {expr} lparen expr rparen
       ;

compare = {cond} cond |
          {gr}compare greater cond |
          {gq}compare greateq cond |
          {ls}compare less cond |
          {lq}compare lesseq cond |
          {eq}compare equal cond |
          {not} not cond
          ;

cond =  {expr} expr |
        {and}  cond and expr |
        {or} cond or expr
        ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really mean to accept conditions "like in C", then you will just make your conditions another form of `expr`, since that is what they are: they are expressions whose value happens to always be in the range `{0, 1}`. But they are not otherwise different:

```
a = (x < y) + 3 * (x == z || x < 6);
```

is a perfectly acceptable expression (although it probably doesn't appear very often in C programs).

So if you just change the last `factor` production to `lparen cond rparen` (or rename `cond` as `expr` and find some other word to name what you are currently calling `expr`), and all the problems with parenthetic conditions will disappear.

There are a number of other SO questions which address this issue. Here are a few:

- [Creating a separate "boolean expression" rule for a dynamic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306448/creating-a-separate-boolean-expression-rule-for-a-dynamic-language)
- [Parsing with parenthesis and different types of expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841509/parsing-with-parenthesis-and-different-types-of-expressions)
- [How to remove shift/reduse warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390843/how-to-remove-shift-reduse-warning)
- [reduce/reduce conflicts using ocamlyacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804411/reduce-reduce-conflicts-using-ocamlyacc)

Comment: Isn't this approach wrong since whenever you want an expression parser can accept condition as well.
eg. for value assignment : id = expr; 
or should I do I deal with it @ semantic analysis?

Comment: @AlexF: That was my point about C, including the example which shows two conditions being used as expressions. If you don't want it to be like C, then you need a different strategy, but (as is indicated in several of the linked questions) it is easiest to do that with a semantic check in the reduce action. (Also you shouldn't say that you want to do it like C :-) )